# DELETE отказывается использовать индекс

Tags: mysql, mariadb, delete

Есть форум на **MariaDB 10.5.21**.
Есть таблица

```
CREATE TABLE `forum_search_matches` (
    `post_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `word_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `subject_match` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    INDEX `forum_search_matches_post_id_idx` (`post_id`),
    INDEX `forum_search_matches_multi_idx` (`word_id`, `post_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

В таблице на данный момент более **25 миллионов** записей.

1.При удалении отдельных или группы сообщений выполняется запрос:

```
DELETE FROM forum_search_matches WHERE post_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Такой запрос выполняется **мгновенно** (0.000 - 0.002 сек).

2.При удаление темы выполняется другой запрос:

```
DELETE
FROM forum_search_matches
WHERE post_id IN (
    SELECT p.id
    FROM forum_posts AS p
    WHERE p.topic_id IN (76002520)
)
```

И тут появляется **проблема**:
EXPLAIN
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Такой запрос выполняется **очень долго**, больше 20 сек.

Как ускорить/исправить запрос DELETE?

Я так понимаю, MariaDB не использует индекс на столбце post_id и перебирает все строки в таблице. Как заставить БД использовать индекс?

P.S. На локальном тестовом форуме с MySQL 8.0.33 и таблицей на 5.7 миллионов записей проблем нет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `show create table forum_posts`

Comment: WHERE IN - самый неудачный вариант связывания. Используй многотабличный DELETE

Comment: @Akina, спасибо! Кажется помогло. Переписал так `DELETE sm FROM forum_posts AS p, forum_search_matches AS sm WHERE p.topic_id IN (76002520) AND sm.post_id=p.id`